# Heroku and DB GUI

Tags: database, heroku

Is there anyway to use a PostgreSQL GUI to modify the database contents without doing a db:pull?

I want to administer my database without taking it off line...

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, you can't...
But, you always can use heroku console and do rails stuff there, which is a good alternative, especially on production when you can't put everything on hold until you pull and push back :)

Answer (score 3):

But you can use:

```
https://github.com/neerajdotname/admin_data
```

to admin your data! It's a gem, I have it working with Heroku on my Rails 3 app.